# how to call the web method only when '/' is the last character from autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-autocomplete

my autocomplete function calls the web method each time a character is entered. I want to call when a character is entered with "/" value at the end.

For ex:"a/"

My autocompleet function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetCus") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('^')[0],
                                val: item.split('^')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
                if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                    $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                    document.getElementById('<%=txtCu.ClientID%>').value = "";
                    return false;
                }
                checkddlcustomerinfo();
            },
            minLength: 0
        }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); })
        .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

            return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<div><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></div>").appendTo(ul);

         };
    });
}
```

Kidnly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

put this after 
    `$(function(){...`

```
var enterFlag =  false;

$("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").on("keypress",function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
           enterFlag =  true;
      }
      else
      {
           enterFlag = false;
      }
});
```

and this goes in your `autocomplete` event

```
if(request.term.indexOf("/") == (request.term.length-1) && enterFlag)
{
                 var term = request.term.slice(0,-1);

                 $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetCus") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('^')[0],
                                val: item.split('^')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.Its very urgent for me.Lat me try it.@Amit Soni

Comment: it is populating those data which have / as a character for example if it type "a/" then it is showing only "A/p infastructure" but i want all those data which starts with a if i type "a/".@Amit Soni

Comment: Try using lastIndexOf()  method as it will always return the last occurance

Comment: slice last index from `request.term` , Answer Updated

Comment: can you just help me.I want to add one more condition to if enter key is pressed then it should fire the event.@AmitSoni

Comment: `Edited` , let me know whether it worked for you or not

Comment: Ok let me try.@AmitSoni

Comment: It is working but on enter key press it is firing another button click event.Can you tell me how to avoid that?@AmitSoni

Comment: @AmitSoni:Can you please help me for giving one solution to my problem.Here is the link for my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154066/how-to-populate-data-in-autocomplete-textbox-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: @sona: ok. let me check

Answer (score 1):

To the last reply: Just change the following
Instead of request.term.indexOf("/"), kindly try with request.term.search("/")

Comment: can you kindly tell me what will it do if i add request.term.search("/")?For the above answer i am getting all values starting with 'a' if i enter 'a/'...But foe a value'a/p infrastructure'  it is unable to find.@useer3672923 @Amit soni