# How to populate data in autocomplete textbox when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-autocomplete

I have a textbox with jquery autocomplete feature.It populates data based on a condition if '/' is entered and then a character.But i want to populate all the data in the autocomplete list when a button is clicked inspite of what ever data is there in the textbox.

My button :

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

And my autocomplete function with condition to populate data is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function pageLoad(sender, args) {
  $(function () {
    $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
         if(request.term.indexOf("/") == (request.term.length-1) && enterFlag)
                {
             var term = request.term.slice(0,-1)
              $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetCus") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                mustMatch: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('^')[0],
                            val: item.split('^')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {

                },
                failure: function (response) {

                 }
              });
           };
         },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                document.getElementById('<%=txtCu.ClientID%>').value = "";
                return false;
            }
            checkddlcustomerinfo();
        },
        minLength: 0
    }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<div><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></div>").appendTo(ul);

     };
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to get the expected result

ASP Button, add class property `CssClass`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn"/>
```

and jQuery Part

```
$(document).on("click","btn",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete("search", "");
     $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete("select",function (e, i) {
        $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
            $("#<%=hdnCr.ClientID %>").val(-1);
            document.getElementById('<%=txtCu.ClientID%>').value = "";
            return false;
        }
        checkddlcustomerinfo();
       }
     );
});
```

to close `autocomplete` on outside `click`

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){ 
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(target.attr("id") != "txtCu" && target.attr("class") != "btn")
    {
        $("#<%=txtCu.ClientID %>").autocomplete('close');

    }
});
```

**Note**: You must set minLength: 0 in your autocomplete

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uRxEf/2)**

Comment: It workrd great.Thanks a lot for all the help.You are really a PRO in coding. @Amit Soni.

Comment: But I am unable to select anything from the autocomplete and as you know i have given condition to check for '/' so it not working for that condition. @Amit Soni.

Comment: Also the autocomplete does not disappear after clicking outside.

Comment: Thnaks.Let me try this code and will let you know.@Amit Soni

Comment: First thing is $(document).on("click","btn",function(e) is not firing button click,it is firing when i am using  $(document).ready(function () {     $('#<%=Button2.ClientID %>').click(function () and the updated answer is not allowing to select value or not disappearing on outside click.@Amit Soni

Comment: I am getting error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: no such method 'select' for autocomplete widget instance".@Amit Soni

Comment: @sona:have you close `script` tag properly, look at [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303850/how-to-solve-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-method-name-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

see this edit to your autocomplete code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetCus") %>',
      data: "{ 'prefix': '" + term + "'}",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      mustMatch: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
           response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                     label: item.split('^')[0],
                     val: item.split('^')[1]
                }
           }))
           $('.ui-autocomplete').hide();   // <-- this line
      },
```

edit XHTML :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" Class="myBtn"/>
```

ps.  it might be `CssClass="myBtn"`  haven't used web forms in a bit

then jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.myBtn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //maybe a prevent propigation line too just for other browsers like IE
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show();
  });
});
```

});

Comment: Thank for replying.       $('.ui-autocomplete').hide(); what this line will do?I don't want to hide the sutocomplete. I want additional button which will populate autocomplete but the previous textbox feature to populate autocomplete will remain same. @Scott Selby

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: I want the autocomplete as it is with the textbox.But want an additional button which will fire the autocomplete event.@Scott Selby.