# How To Add Search Button To Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-plugins

[This](http://myblogmyupdatesv.blogspot.in/)
is my blog.

This is the code

```
<!doctype html>
Jquery Auto Complete

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [
             { value: "NYC", url: 'http://www.nyc.com' }, 
             { value: "LA", url: 'http://www.la.com' },
             { value: "Philly", url: 'http://www.philly.com' },
             { value: "Chitown", url: 'http://www.chitown.com' },
             { value: "DC", url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com' },
             { value: "SF", url: 'http://www.sanfran.com' },
             { value: "Peru", url: 'http://www.peru.com' }
        ],
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        }

});
  });
  </script>



<input id="autocomplete" />


</!doctype>
```

Now when ever the user search for query NYC and when it is selected is redirecting to the url but my aim is to put search button beside when the user clicks the search button then it should be redirected. I hope my question is clear thanks in advance.

Comment: In select: $("input#autocomplete").attr("data-url", ui.item.url); Then access data-url of autocomplete on click of button

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154066/how-to-populate-data-in-autocomplete-textbox-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full Updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
var selectedItemUrl = "";
$(function() {

  var source = [{
    value: "NYC",
    url: 'http://www.nyc.com'
  }, {
    value: "LA",
    url: 'http://www.la.com'
  }, {
    value: "Philly",
    url: 'http://www.philly.com'
  }, {
    value: "Chitown",
    url: 'http://www.chitown.com'
  }, {
    value: "DC",
    url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com'
  }, {
    value: "SF",
    url: 'http://www.sanfran.com'
  }, {
    value: "Peru",
    url: 'http://www.peru.com'
  }];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: source,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      selectedItemUrl = ui.item.url
    }
  })

});

function SearchItem(e){
if(selectedItemUrl!="")
    window.location=selectedItemUrl
    else
    alert("select something to search")

}


</script>


</head>
<body>
<input id="autocomplete" />
<button onclick='SearchItem()'>
Search
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Please mark as an answer if it helps u now :0 ,:)

Comment: I have Updated the answer now you can check its working

Comment: okay lets clear few things. You want Search button inside the autocomplete widget or outside?

Comment: outside parshant i mean when user clicks search button after selecting any of the tags it should be redirected to that page like google does i hope u understand

Comment: prashant but tags are not blinking and also when i typed nyc they are not linked i dont know wht happened

Comment: Have you included jquery-ui.min.js  and jquery-ui.css?

Comment: no i have not included please paste all the code so that i can understand .. if any demo could help me

Comment: Okkay buddy.. Just copy and paste the following code. Ull get what u want

Comment: Thank you very much it worked what i want really appreciable. Morning onwards iam searching for this thanks once again prashant it worked like bullet thanks once again.

Comment: ok one thing inside the search bar if i want to add any quotes like search any thing city, address like this where should i put.............? i mean what you are looking for i want to add inside the search bar just paragraph to understand for the user

Comment: Sorry prashant iam new user so I'am not able to mark it as answer it is asking me more reputation and also last help how to add some paragraph inside the search bar like search what your looking for.......?

Comment: marked prashant but last question how to add some paragraph inside search bar i mean like what you are looking for? how to add this

Comment: Sorry brother, M going off duty right now. Cant help you. Hope you understand